# Python equivalent of EE 'require'

Tags: python, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to link to the amazing [CCDC tools module](https://gee-ccdc-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

In EE JS interface, we use:

```
var utils = require('users/parevalo_bu/gee-ccdc-tools:ccdcUtilities/api')
```

I cannot find a workaround in Python to get access to the module and be able to utilize the tools.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesntt. I have tried that and the geemap JS conversion returns an empty dictionary. The only comment that may help is :ust go to the script path?" but to be honest i dont understand how to implement that.

Comment: The key point in that answer is that there is no Python equivalent of `require`. Therefore, in order to use CCDC tools module in your Python code, the module must be written in Python. Then you can use `import cdcc_module_name` to access the module. I don't know if there is a tool to run JavaScript code in Python.

Comment: I think this is a GEE utility that you need to find the modules. Have a look at https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fclim.2020.576740/full, which says *The CCDC algorithm, originally developed in MATLAB and later implemented as a Python package by USGS-EROS as part of the LCMAP initiative (Brown et al., 2020), has been recently implemented as a temporal segmentation algorithm in GEE by Noel Gorelick, Zhiqiang Yang, and the Earth Engine Team and will be formally described by their authors in an upcoming publication (Google, 2020).*